# What is the location of Update and Delete constraint values in Sybase IQ?

Tags: sql, sap-iq, database-metadata

In MS SQL @DB_Name.sys.foreign_keys keeps this values in (update|delete)_referential_action columns. Where can I find them in Sybase IQ? Do values equal to MS SQL indexes/values? Thank you.

```
MS:
0 = No action
1 = Cascade
2 = Set null
3 = Set default
```

I am using Sybase IQ 15.4.

---

**UPDATE:** I found referential_action column from "SYSTRIGGER" view, but it doesn't contain any records for my foreign keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looks like IQ does not have such mechanism and referential_action options described on [this](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1540/doc/html/san1278453376212.html) page is possibly does not relate to IQ directly but is a part of ASE or other product.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at SYSFKEY, it could solve your problem.

Comment: Sybase IQ 15.4. It does not contain the values, that i was searching for in SYSFKEY.

Comment: Cannot check but you may also try: SYSIDX / SYSIDXCOL.

Comment: well, the thing is that i already found where values should be. It's [SYSTRIGGER](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1540/doc/html/saiq-systrigger-system-view.html) view. But SYSTRIGGER is empty and does not provide access to change this values